# GoLang: Если я вдруг забуду rows.Close()

Tags: golang

Будет ли утечка памяти если я вдруг забуду rows.Close()

Пример кода:

```go
import (
 "sql"
)

func query() {
 q := db.Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE banned = 0")
 for q.Next() {
  // Что-то
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Close closes the Rows, preventing further enumeration. If Next is
> called and returns false and there are no further result sets, the
> Rows are closed automatically and it will suffice to check the result
> of Err. Close is idempotent and does not affect the result of Err.

Если `Next` был вызван и вернул `false`(то есть больше записей нет), то `Close()` будет вызван автоматически.

В вашем примере вы перебираете все элементы. Если нет точек выхода, то переживать не стоит. Но не все так просто.

Вероятнее, внутри цикла придется скинаровать резлуьтат в переменную. Сканирование может вернуть ошибку, а вы передадите ошибку выше, не закрыв Rows. Поэтому, лучше всегда закрывать, вызывая `defer q.Close()`